# Unresolved reference in Kotlin using JNI-Bridge

Tags: kotlin, java-native-interface

I want to call the `startOsc()`function inside of a Composable in Kotlin and get this error: `Unresolved reference: startOsc`

This is my Kotlin code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private external fun startEngine()
    private external fun stopEngine()
    private external fun startOsc() // <-- here the function is defined

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("pitch_andoid")
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TwoNotesView()
        }
        startEngine()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        stopEngine()
    }
}

@Composable
fun TwoNotesView() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.cyan))
    ) {
        Row {
            Box (
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        startOsc() // <-- this is the line of the error 
                    }
                    ) {
                AnswerButton(ImageSource = R.drawable.round_replay_24_cyan) // this is some other composable I left out for simplicity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt is probably correct, since there is no Unresolved Reference for `startEngine()` and `stopEngine()`.
Here is the code of the jni-bridge.cpp for the `startOsc()`function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_pitch_1andoid_MainActivity_startOsc(JNIEnv *env, jobject/* this */) {
    audioEngine->setToneOn(true);
}
```

I made a spelling mistake naming the project, that's why everything is called "andoid" instead of "android", Sorry.

edit: the error has to be passing down the function from MainActivity to the Composable. I tried calling the function inside MainActivity and got no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by passing down `startOsc()` like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private external fun startEngine()
    private external fun stopEngine()
    external fun startOsc() // <-- deleted 'private'

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("pitch_andoid")
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TwoNotesView(::startOsc) // <-- pass down startOsc() as parameter
        }
        startEngine()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        stopEngine()
    }
}

@Composable
fun TwoNotesView(startOsc: () -> Unit) { // <-- add startOsc() as parameter

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.cyan))
    ) {
        Row {
            Box (
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        startOsc()
                    }
                    ) {
                AnswerButton(ImageSource = R.drawable.round_replay_24_cyan) // this is some other composable I left out for simplicity
            }
        }
    }
}
```